# Why is Batman dressed like a bat?

Tags: dc, batman

Why is Batman dressed like a bat? Why a bat? Why not just like a black suit of some kind? I just don't get it. I've already tried searching on google, but it gave me nothing, so if some of you guys could help me, that would be great.

Comment: Duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59877/why-are-batman-s-cape-and-cowl-blue/59880#59880?

Comment: @Richard Feel free to reject the migration then, so we can change it to apply to the Nolan movies and reopen it on the other site.

Comment: @TARS - The OP doesn't state that he's after a movie quote. I've also no intention of playing ping-pong with the question. It's on topic, i'm just thinking it's a dupe.

Comment: @Richard Well, still a pity if it just gets closed (especially as a duplicate of a totally different question). In this case I'd rather opted to specify the question instead of migrate it. But alas.

Comment: Because _Officeman_ doesn't sound nearly as cool as Batman.

Comment: I think it's explained in one of the Michael Keaton movies and in one of the Christian Bale movies, although the explanations are quite different. It looks like Gotham is going to provide yet another different explanation when they get around to it. Reading [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Kane), one might infer that the "bat" connection was almost random in a mad dash to come up with a new hero to follow on the success of Superman.

Answer (score 9):

Strictly from the point of movies, there is this conversation with Alfred:

> **Bruce:** As a man, I'm flesh and blood, I can be ignored, destroyed. But as a symbol... As a symbol, I can be incorruptible. I can be
>   everlasting.
>   **Alfred:** What symbol?
>   **Bruce:** Something elemental... something terrifying.

Later on, this conversation takes place as Bruce is preparing his toys:

> **Alfred:** Why bats, Master Wayne?
>   **Bruce:** Bats frighten me. It's time my enemies shared my dread.

The whole movie is revolving around fear. A ninja dressed as a bat gives away a supernatural feel to his enemies, inducing fear in them. Just take a look at mighty Falcone, how panicked he gets on his first encounter with the Batman.

"Theatricality and deception are powerful agents" and Bruce took Ra's' "advice about theatricality a bit literally". Hence, the suit reflecting what Bruce fears due to his childhood trauma: the bat.

Answer (score 3):

In terms specifically of the films, this is explained in the 2005 film [Batman Begins](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372784/) , which relates the story of how Bruce Wayne becomes Batman.

A frightening encounter with bats in Bruce Wayne's early life leaves a mark on him and he decides to use that when he starts to fight evil.

In terms of the character as a whole - that is another matter.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly talking of the suit : It is indeed a black suit of some kind.
Remember the suit is not designed by Bruce, but by Lucius Fox.
every component of the suit serves some purpose. And if I correctly remember
the suit along with the Batpod was designed for some military program.The bat wing type cape is supposed to help the person fly. The headgear which look like a Bat's ears also has some kind of transmitter or something installed in it.

I think all the changes made by Bruce to this suit was getting it in Black.

Nonetheless My point is - Do not look on the batsuit like spiderman's suit which Peter parker designed himself.

And anyways it works nicely for Bruce, because his impersonation of Bat (his great fear) means him overcoming his fear.
That's my take on it.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is only true of the Nolan films.  Plenty of Batman stories in other media have Wayne designing the suit himself.